# Perl: how can i pass list to script?

Tags: perl, list, command-line-arguments

i need to pass list  to my script 
how can i do it?

for example i have script: flow.pl 
i need to pass to it list of fubs :

```
fub1, fub2, fub3
```

and path to database1 =

```
path1
```

and path to database2 =

```
path2
```

and how can i get this parameters?

```
 (through $ARGV[i]?)
```

if i do:

```
flow.pl fub1,fub2,fub3 path1 path2
```

and in the code:

```
$listoffubs = $ARGV[0]
$path1 = $ARGV[1]
$path2 = $ARGV[2]
```

list of fubs get name of fubs like one word.

Answer (score 7):

Having lists of positional arguments is ok as long as the lists are short and simple. Once you get into a larger number of arguments or you have arguments with an internal structure, then you probably want to look at named arguments.

In this case, I think I'd be looking at using [GetOpt::Long](https://metacpan.org/module/Getopt::Long) to implement named arguments.

Answer (score 5):

Simply split the list:

```
my @ListOfFubs = split /,/ ,  $listoffubs;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your arguments will be space separated, so yes, `fub1,fub2,fub3` will be one argument. Just use space instead, and you'll be fine. E.g.:

```
flow.pl fub1 fub2 fub3 path1 path2

my $fub1 = shift;     # first argument is removed from ARGV and assigned to $fub1
```

Or

```
my $fub1 = $ARGV[0];  # simple assignment
```

All at once

```
my ($fub1,$fub2,$fub3,$path1,$path2) = @ARGV;  # all are assigned at once
```

Note that using [`shift`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html) is removing arguments from `@ARGV`.

If you have a list of arguments that may vary, it is a simple fix to put them last, and then do:

```
flow.pl path1 path2 fub1 fub2 fub3 ... fubn

my $path1 = shift;
my $path2 = shift;  # remove first two arguments, then
my @fubs  = @ARGV;  # assign the rest of the args to an array
```

For more complicated argument handling, use a module, such as [Getopt::Long](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Getopt%3a%3aLong).